# Converting graphs to sets of paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

I have an Euclidean, undirected graph: each vertex is a point on the 2D plane, so the weight of each edge is the Euclidean distance between the vertices.

- The number of vertices with no edges is small in comparison to the total number of vertices.
- No vertex has more than two edges connected to it.

How can I convert this graph to a closed shape, so each vertex will have exactly two edges connected to it and there will be a path between any two vertices? I want to do it with minimum change in the total weight of all the edges.

Comment: Is your graph guaranteed to be *planar* or may edges cross?

Comment: @reinierpost edges may cross

Comment: So there are no paths of length 2 or more in the original graph?

Comment: @reinierpost I didn't say that. It might be

Comment: So you're looking for a cycle that contains all vertices? Maybe you want to start with a collection of cycles, 2-matchings are [polytime solvable](http://books.google.de/books?id=mqGeSQ6dJycC&pg=PA522&lpg=PA522&dq=%222-matching%22+polytope&source=bl&ots=xPNNKXjpMb&sig=Jxo4Tm9NptYZLT-f8rcVUXNDS54&hl=de&sa=X&ei=dYtnUszkMsTXsgbtjIFQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%222-matching%22%20polytope&f=false)

Comment: @adrianN yes I am looking for cycle that contains all the vertices, but collection of cycles is not helping me

Comment: This might be equivalent to TSP in euclidean graphs, although no reduction is apparent to me so far. You somehow have to build graphs with $\mathbb{o}(|V|)$ disconnected vertices, and once you succeed in doing that, NP-hardness follows since if I remember correctly, euclidean TSP is NP-hard. I don't see how to do that, though.

Comment: @Babidu: You did imply that by saying 'No vertex has more than one edge connected to it.'

Comment: @reinierpost Sorry I did a mistake. Edited it

Comment: @Babidu: OK ... so it really is just a set of paths?

Comment: @reinierpost yep. Also if there is any thing more, than ask me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11179/convert-graph-to-close-shape)

Comment: I have edited the title to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

This should be NP-hard, here's a way you could try to do a reduction:

Take any graph $G$ embedded in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. Let $c_{min} = \min_{e \in E}\{c(e)\}$  be the minimum edge weight in the graph ($c$ is the weight function of the edges of $G$, i.e. the euclidean distance). To build $G'$, split every vertex $v = (x,y)$ into $v_1 = v$ and $v_2 = (x+\epsilon,y)$ where $\epsilon = \frac{c_{min}}{2^n}$, connect $v_1$ and $v_2$ with an edge weighted by their euclidean distance. Obviously, no vertex in $G'$ is incident with more than two edges, and there are no vertices that are incident with no edges.

What you now would have to prove is something like "there's a TSP route of weight $\le w$ in $G$ iff there's a TSP route of weight $\le w + n \cdot \epsilon$ in $G'$. I don't know how to prove that, but some geometry and use of the triangle inequality might help. I expect the choice of $\epsilon$ as vanishingly small will be enough to give the reduction.

EDIT: The reduction will remain valid after your edit.

Comment: Looking again on my old questions. There is a polynomial solution for this one with $O(n^4)$, [2-opt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt). If you be able to reduce it to NP-Complete problem it will be extremely interesting.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and I may be wrong), 2-opt is a heuristic, not a solution.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH/LKH-2.0/DOC/LKH_REPORT.pdf) article, it says 2-opt is solution.

Comment: I couldn't find that it claimed anywhere that 2-opt is an exact solution instead of just an approximation algorithm, nor that it runs in polynomial time.

Comment: I probably didn't explain my self well. 2-opt does not solve the TSP it just run in polynomial time.

Comment: An algorithm that runs in polynomial time but doesn't solve the problem isn't really interesting.

Comment: It does not solve TSP but it is the solution for that question I asked.